# Embedding version control of the weaviate

Tags: version-control, word-embedding, weaviate, approximate-nn-searching

In [Weaviate](https://weaviate.io/), the vector engine, I wonder how this can handle version issue of embedding model.

For instance, considering the (trained) word2vec model, embedded vectors from different models must be seperated.

One option might think is that make distinct multiple classes representing model version.
Custom script may useful. If new model available, create new class and import accorded data. After that, change (GET) entrypoints (used for searching nearest vectors) to the new class.

Or maybe weaviate have other fancy way to handle this issue, but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at version 1.17.3, you have to manage this yourself because weaviate only supports one embedding per object.

There is a feature request to allow multiple embeddings per object [here](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/2465). But it sounds like your request is closer to this [one](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/2570). In any case, have a look at them and upvote the one that addresses your need so the engineering team can prioritize accordingly. Also, feel free to raise a new feature request if neither of these addresses your needs.